# How to locate the theme folder in Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I'm binding some image controls dynamically but don't set image URL. When I use a skin file and then set the SkinId, I get the following error:

```
The 'SkinId' property can only be set in or before the Page_PreInit event for static controls. For dynamic controls, set the property before adding it to the Controls collection.
```

How do I get a virtual theme's location?

Comment: The error message you are getting does not have anything to do with the location of the theme. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I need to set image url dynamically. But image located on Theme folder

Answer (score 1):

Set the SkinId on the markup

```
<asp:Image runat="server" id="LogoImage" SkinId="LogoImage" />
```

To set it programatically you need to set it up on the PreInit event

```
public void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  LogoImage.SkinID = "LogoImage";
}
```

And here is a blog post for setting the SkinId Programatically
http://blogs.conchango.com/simonevans/archive/2005/06/09/How-to-programmatically-assign-a-SkinID-to-a-control-while-using-a-master-page-in-ASP.net-2.0.aspx

Finally, if you are just looking for the folder, it depends on whether you are using a [Theme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.theme.aspx) or a [StylesheetTheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.stylesheettheme.aspx).

```
var path = "~/App_Themes/" + Page.Theme + "/images";
var path = "~/App_Themes/" + Page.StylesheetTheme + "/images";
```

### Update

If you doing this in a Grid use a custom binding method

```
<asp:Image runat="server" id="myImage" ImageUrl='<%# GetThemedImage(((Product)Container.DataItem).Image)%>' />
```

then in the code-behind

```
public string GetThemedImage(string image)
{
     return "~/App_Themes/" + Page.Theme + "/images/" + image;
}
```

Comment: how to set SkinId dynamically?

Comment: i'm using grid and put image control on the template.First I'm get handle of image control.After I need to set image url on the Grid databinding event